# How to see hidden hard drives

Tags: windows

I have few hidden drives on domain. I can mount drives with .bat script exmpl:

```
net use X: /delete /y
net use X: "\\link-to-drive\groups$"
```

and script gives to my new drive X. 
How I can get all hidden drives names on my domain because manually  run this script and just queues take time.